# Dockerfile split

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

My python folder structure is as below

```
|_ _ helper
|_ _ Action1
|_ _ Action2


Action1 and Action2 use helper package .
```

**I want to make dockerfile which is split as below**

```
Docker file Base -> which contains common packages like pika which are necessary to build Action1 and Action2


Individual docker file images -> Individual docker file for Action1 and Action2 modules.
```

Since I cannot do cd .. inside Action1 and Action2 since docker context is sent to daemon whenever dockerfile is built.

Please suggest how to proceed on the above

Answer (score 1):

In `docker build` command you can specify which folder is your root folder (the context) - this is the last argument `../` in the example below.

Assuming your dockerfile inside `Action1` folder and your present working directory `Action1` you can run:

`~/Action1# docker build -f dockerfile -t <image_name> ../`

**Note/Tip:** you can add `.dockerignore` file in the parent directory to reduce the time that's take docker to load your context into memory (if parent directory is too big.

Good luck!